# Install script curl'ed from github:

Tags: bash, curl

I have the following script hosted on Github:
https://rawgit.com/oresoftware/quicklock/master/install.sh

the contents of that file are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e;
cd "$HOME"
mkdir -p "$HOME/.quicklock/locks"
curl https://rawgit.com/oresoftware/quicklock/master/install.sh > "$HOME/.quicklock/ql.sh"

echo "To complete installation of 'quicklock' add the following line to your .bash_profile file:";
echo ". \"$HOME/.quicklock/ql.sh\"";
```

I download and run this script with:

```
curl -o- https://rawgit.com/oresoftware/quicklock/master/install.sh | bash
```

but I get this error:

> bash: line 1: Moved: command not found

That error is killing me, I cannot figure out what is causing it. I tried curl with both the `-o-` option and without.

Comment: That URL has moved to a different location, the 'moved' is a redirect response from the server.  Try this instead:  `wget https://rawgit.com/oresoftware/quicklock/master/install.sh ; bash ./install.sh`

Comment: `curl -L https://rawgit.com/oresoftware/quicklock/master/install.sh | bash` 
 .....worked....but I am not sure why

Comment: `man curl`  -L follows redirect responses.  `wget` apparently does this by default.

Comment: thanks, yeah might have to give users an example of using wget too

Comment: `wget  -q -O - https://rawgit.com/oresoftware/quicklock/master/install.sh | bash`

Comment: yeah I stole this technique from https://github.com/creationix/nvm and they do just like you said.... `wget -q0 ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url for raw git has changed, the error itsel is from curl.

Change `rawgit.com` to `raw.githubusercontent.com`.

Another option is to add `-L` to have `curl` follow the redirect link.

I figured this out by changing `bash` to `bash -x`.  Here is the output:

```
curl -o- https://rawgit.com/oresoftware/quicklock/master/install.sh | bash -x
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   107  100   107    0     0    400      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   402
+(:1): Moved Permanently. Redirecting to https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oresoftware/quicklock/master/install.sh
bash: line 1: Moved: command not found
```

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work...I think it actually needs `-L` instead.

Comment: what worked seems to be `curl -o- ...` no sure why, but that's what `nvm` uses if you are familiar with nvm

Answer (score 0):

@xxfelixxx is pretty much right

This was sort of nightmare, but there appears to be a redirect even when using `raw.githubusercontent.com`

the only thing that worked with `curl` was to use:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oresoftware/quicklock/master/install.sh | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

For the scripts that require arguments, you can do `_` for the script placeholder and then the arguments. For exampe: example.sh that expects `--help`

```bash
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<USER>/<NAME>/<BRANCH>/example.sh | bash -s _ --help
```