# Is it possible to use fzf (command line fuzzy finder) with windows 10 git-bash?

Tags: windows, bash, git-bash, fuzzy-search, fzf

I downloaded the .exe file and placed it into my PATH variable. `fzf` seems to work in command prompt. But I would like to use it in git-bash. When i use `fzf` in git-bash it seems to start but nothing happens.

Any advice would be helpful. I'm trying to save myself some keystrokes.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is.

I just downloaded `fzf.exe` from [fzf-bin](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/releases), launched `bash.exe`, and typed `./fzf.exe`

But for that, I use a simplified `PATH` first:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%
```

With that PATH, `fzf` just works.

[image: fzf in bash]

Comment: Thanks, to then integrate it with bash's `CTRL`+`R` history search is there a simpler way than cloning the fzf repo to `~/.fzf` and then running `~/.fzf/install`?

Comment: @SamHasler you could only curl that single file `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/fzf/master/install|bash`, as in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063127/6309

Comment: ```$ set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
>
bash: C:WINDOWS: command not found
bash: C:WINDOWSSystem32Wbem: command not found
bash: C:WINDOWSSystem32WindowsPowerShellv1.0: command not found

$ set GH=C:\myprog\Git
$ set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%
bash: fg: %GH%usrbin: no such job
bash: fg: %GH%mingw64bin: no such job
bash: fg: %GH%mingw64libexecgit-core: no such job
bash: fg: %PATH%: no such job
```
Only setting GH worked for me. Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: @Tablut Those `set` commands are meant to be executed in a `CMD` session. *Then*, from that same `CMD` session, you type `bash` to enter a `bash` session.

Comment: Is what file do we add the three set statements?

Comment: @phage They are not in a file. They are typed and executed directly in the CMD, in order to change the PATH for that CMD session.

Comment: The repository has been moved as `fzf` only. This is the updated link (https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/releases) for releases.

Comment: @CompaqLE2202x Thank you for the feedback. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was a while ago, but hopefully I can be of some use for any new readers trying to get fuzzy finder working, in git-bash

For whatever reason, I had tried the package from the GitHub repo @VonC shared and the new repo linked thereof and neither package executed in terminal as expected - Only thing could do was `fzf --help`

---

As you know git-bash is based on MSYS2, and they have pacman to install packages and a package list can also be found here https://packages.msys2.org/package/ including a fuzzy finder, however not fzf, but [fzy](https://packages.msys2.org/package/fzy)

To get the Windows compatible file, go straight to 'File', not the upstream URL and within the downloaded compressed file you will find the .exe

Move that .exe to your git-bash /usr/bin and either rename fzy.exe to fzf.exe or bash alias fzf to execute fzy

Answer (score 0):

Put the fzf.exe file in the `cmd` folder under `Git`.  So for me it would be
`C:\Users\<<username>>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd`