# Failed to init source control in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control

Here below are outputs I got when I opened my vscode, and vscode source control does not work any more after that.

Tried to reinstall Git or vscode for many times but no help. But I have no idea how vscode runs Git inside.

```
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
Using git  from C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
> git rev-parse --git-dir
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
> git rev-parse --git-dir
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
> git rev-parse --git-dir
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
> git rev-parse --git-dir
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
> git rev-parse --git-dir
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
> git rev-parse --git-dir
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
> git rev-parse --git-dir
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and open VSCode from command line, in the root folder of your repository:

```
cd c:\path\to\repo
"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" -n .
```

See if the error message persists then.

Do not open it in `c:\path\to\repo\.git`.

Comment: Thank you for your answering VonC, I tried your command just now but the error messages remain the same. It seems like to me that vscode tries to connect its source control stuff somewhere else (not the dir where my repo lies in).

Comment: @Prisoner Did you use a final '.' in the command I mention? To force it to open on that folder?

Comment: @Prisoner See also https://github.com/DonJayamanne/gitHistoryVSCode/issues/233#issuecomment-375769718: on Windows, in a CMD, type `set GIT_DIR`, and check if it returns a non-empty value. If yes, make sure to unset GIT_DIR.

Comment: @Prisoner Check also what kind of plugin you have installed. Do you have gitHistoryVSCode?

Comment: Yep I did type that '.' in the end. After typing `set GIT_DIR`, I get an empty value. Just checked , i do not have gitHistoryVSCode plugin or any other git plugin installed.

Comment: @Prisoner OK, and I suppose your Git for Widows is the latest Git 2.29.2?

Comment: `git --verison` shows `git version 2.29.2.windows.2`, should i install an older version of git instead?

Comment: @Prisoner Was it working at anytime before? What settings do you have in VSCode regarding git?

Comment: `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
  "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "-l"
  ]`
Yeah that source control thing works until this Tuesday.

Comment: @Prisoner Do you have the setting `git.path` set?

Comment: @Prisoner Can you try and launch vscode as mentioned in the answer, but in a CMD with a simplified PATH? (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63835684/6309)

Comment: no I cannot launch vscode in a CMD with a simplified PATH, I got `bash: fg: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd: no such job`

Comment: @Prisoner bash? Are you in a git bash session? Or in a regular CMD?

Comment: I was in bash, just tried regular CMD too, vscode opened, the same error message pops up..

Comment: @Prisoner Yes, forget bash: everything I mention is in the context of a regular CMD. Did you set a simplified PATH in the CMD before launching VSCode?

Comment: Yes sir, I did set `%LOCALAPPDATA%` before entering the cmd in a cmd, vscode opened up but the error message is still there :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224829/discussion-between-vonc-and-prisoner).