# Git - slow fetch - credential manager host providers

Tags: windows, git

I have noticed that git operations slowed down recently, it might be related to the upgrade of git and using credential-manager-core instead of credential-manager, I've tried to diagnose the issue using `GCM_TRACE=1 git fetch`, looks like I might have messed up my configuration:

`[GetProviderAsync] Checking against 3 host providers registered with priority 'Normal'.`

My colleague does not see such line and only one host provider is checked. How can I change the configuration of host providers used by git credential manager?

Update:
Using a portable version of git did not help, trace output below:

```
[RunInternalAsync] Version: 2.0.394.50751
[RunInternalAsync] Runtime: .NET Framework 4.0.30319.42000
[RunInternalAsync] Platform: Windows (x86-64)
[RunInternalAsync] AppPath: git-credential-manager-core
[RunInternalAsync] Arguments: get
[ExecuteAsync] Start 'get' command...
[ExecuteAsync] Detecting host provider for input:
[ExecuteAsync]   protocol=https
[ExecuteAsync]   host=dev.azure.com
[ExecuteAsync]   path=........
[ExecuteAsync]   username=........
[GetProviderAsync] Performing auto-detection of host provider.
[GetProviderAsync] Checking against 3 host providers registered with priority 'Normal'.
[ExecuteAsync] Host provider 'Azure Repos' was selected.
[GetCredentialAsync] Looking for existing credential in store with service=https://........ account=...
[GetCredentialAsync] Existing credential found.
[ExecuteAsync] End 'get' command...
[RunInternalAsync] Version: 2.0.394.50751
[RunInternalAsync] Runtime: .NET Framework 4.0.30319.42000
[RunInternalAsync] Platform: Windows (x86-64)
[RunInternalAsync] AppPath: git-credential-manager-core
[RunInternalAsync] Arguments: store
[ExecuteAsync] Start 'store' command...
[ExecuteAsync] Detecting host provider for input:
[ExecuteAsync]   protocol=https
[ExecuteAsync]   host=........
[ExecuteAsync]   path=................
[ExecuteAsync]   username=..............
[ExecuteAsync]   password=********
[GetProviderAsync] Performing auto-detection of host provider.
[GetProviderAsync] Checking against 3 host providers registered with priority 'Normal'.
[ExecuteAsync] Host provider 'Azure Repos' was selected.
[StoreCredentialAsync] Storing credential with service=............. account=...............
[StoreCredentialAsync] Credential was successfully stored.
[ExecuteAsync] End 'store' command...
```

Number of registered host providers seems suspicious but I do not know how it can be changed.
Also - storing credentials on each fetch does not seem like an efficient thing to do.

Update 2:
Switching to SSH authorization did not help much, so the root cause of delays is not related to GCM. I'll investiage a bit more and probably close the question.

Comment: Did you use a portable Git with a `%PATH%` which *only* referenced that Git, and no other programs? (to minimize any side effect from other programs)

Comment: Yes, the only thing that was common with my previous setup is a change to gitconfig: `[credential] useHttpPath = true helper = manager-core`

Comment: Does the issue persists when there are less entries (like no entry for `dev.azure.com` for example)? DO you reproduce the issue with the same latest Git (2.31.1) on other machines?

Comment: The thing is that I do not know how to change host providers used by git credential managers, docs are scarce for that subject. Deleting credentials stored in windows Credential Manager does not help - they are recreated after fetch, revoking PATs in Azure Devops also does not help.

Comment: I cannot attempt a repro on other machine with my account due to security, colleagues do not have this issue, the difference is that they have only one host provider mentioned in trace.

Comment: The latest GCM release does remove those messages. See [my updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66838111/6309) below.

Answer (score 2):

I did not use the git trace as you did when I had a similar issue, but I was getting 3 "detecting host provider for" messages every time I did a fetch. I was on git 2.33.1.windows.1 and wasn't using https remotes before then. (2.33.1 stopped allowing rsa/sha-1 keys apparently, and I switched to personal access tokens while troubleshooting.) I was already using credential manager core so my solution was to add a credential.provider setting to .gitconfig telling it that I am connecting to a bitbucket server.

```
[credential]
    helper = manager-core
[credential "https://example.com"]
    provider = bitbucket
```

After doing this I don't get any "detecting host provider" messages and git fetch runs much faster now.
https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/main/docs/configuration.md

Comment: Do you have any idea what should be the configuration for gitlab? I was having two lines of `detecting host provider` with gitlab. I added `provider = generic` for it, and it increased to three. `auto` works like no config - two messages.

Comment: I would try all of the possibilities to see if any of the others gave a better result since "auto" is finding a way that works. I did find an open issue to add gitlab as a credential provider. Or you can ignore all of that and use SSH.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/225215

Comment: At work, I had issues to set it up with corporate GitHub and Bitbucket as well (I guess that we're using some older version). But you're right, I'll go with SSH. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Test if this is linked to your current [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) installation by:

- uncompressing the portable version (like [`PortableGit-2.31.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.31.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.31.1-64-bit.7z.exe), auto-extractible) in a new folder (`C:\git` for instance)
- setting a custom [simplified `%PATH%`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63835684/6309) in a CMD session

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%
```

- checking if the issue persists on `git fetch`

That way, you don't disturb your current setup, and limit your tests to a single CMD session.

---

Update Nov. 2021: [Git-Credential-Manager-Core v2.0.603](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/releases/tag/v2.0.603) does remove those messages.
It is not yet packaged with the [latest Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), like [the recent 2.34.0](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.34.0.windows.1), but expect it in 2.34.1.