# fzf not workign with git bash (installation via scoop)

Tags: bash, fzf

I installed fzf via scoop on windows 10 but unfortunately it works well on cmd but impossible to make it work on git bash. I found a similar topic here: [Is it possible to use fzf (command line fuzzy finder) with windows 10 git-bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61943778/is-it-possible-to-use-fzf-command-line-fuzzy-finder-with-windows-10-git-bash)
but i don't understand these commands at all.
I checked the shims( the Windows command-line installer.) files of fzf and I have this as path

```
path = "C:\Users\<user name>\scoop\apps\fzf\current\fzf.exe"
```

fzf works fine on cmd but I need the bash interpreter. It's very annoying, anyone have an idea?
When I write

```
`fzf --help`
```

the command is recognized on git bash, it means that the command works but it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 (git bash) - try `winpty fzf`
You can also set an alias in `.bashrc`:

```
alias fzf="winpty fzf"
```